# RecylerView works without fragments. Doesnt work when I use fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am starting to learn Android and am facing some difficulty using fragments. Could you please help me to figure out what the issue is? Everything else apart from what is mentioned below is the same in both the projects

```
1. Code without fragments (works totally fine. Gives a simple list with some data):



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(generatePalettes()));
}



2. Code with Fragment (doesnt work. Blank Screen):



    MainActivity
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
            }
        }



    MainActivityFragment    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new PaletteAdapter(generatePalettes()));
            return rootView;
        }
```

*--------------------------------UPDATE-------------*

Code changed to the following: Still doesnt work. Blank screen shown. Tried putting the UI update in both onActivityCreated and in onViewCreated(). Gist with code here: https://gist.github.com/adityarb88/12f5ccce665afbf58069

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new PaletteAdapter(generatePalettes()));
    }
```

Comment: May be `if (savedInstanceState == null) {` condition not satisfy.

Comment: Hi Piyush. Thanks for your response. I debugged and it does satisfy. I created a gist just in case you wanted to refer the code:

https://gist.github.com/adityarb88/12f5ccce665afbf58069

Comment: @takeradi, don't do UI changes in 'onCreateView' but do them in 'onActivityCreated' for your fragment

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I put the UI changes in onActivityCreated() just like inner class suggested below. It still shows a blank screen. I have the code in the gist above. Thanks again!

Comment: @takeradi, kindly remove 'if (savedInstanceState == null) ' condition

Comment: did that too. unfortunately that doesnt work too. i get a blank screen. not sure whats wrong.

Comment: @takeradi, in gist shows that you are showing recyclerview in 'onViewCreated' instead of 'onActivityCreated', and you have to reference recycleView in onCreateView

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I mentioned that in the update above. I tried both onActivityCreated and onViewCreated. Doesnt work in both of them. The gist does show onViewCreated. And I am not referencing recyclerView in onCreateView.

Comment: no luck. tried the code you mentioned below. thanks for your help anyway Pankaj. I will try to debug more.

Comment: @takeradi, are you trying to replace a framelayout id in this line in your MainActivity 'R.id.container'

Comment: @takeradi it's not the code but it's the layout which is messed up,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this problem. Firstly, Thanks Pankaj. You were partially correct. My layout was indeed incorrect. So:
 1. I did change that to a RelativeLayout but I added the fragment to my activity programatically. 
 2. To see things more clearly, I changed the background of the Activity
    and the fragment and added margins and paddings respectively.

After doing this I still couldnt populate the recycler view even though I knew that my fragment was being added correctly. So the error was in the PaletteAdapter class.

```
 public PaletteAdapter(List<Palette> palettes){
        this.palettes = new ArrayList<Palette>();
        this.palettes.addAll(palettes);
    }
```

I was missing the this in front of palettes.addAll(palettes). Hence the list was empty. I have uploaded the code to a new gist in case anyone wants to refer it:

https://gist.github.com/adityarb88/c6109fc1d8a796383c71

Answer (score 1):

For your Fragments setup adapters after you build your views:

MainActivityFragment

This method should only inflate and return your view:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Then in `onViewCreated(View, Bundle)` or `onActivityCreated(Bundle):`

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      // getView() returns your Fragments root view
      RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new PaletteAdapter(generatePalettes()));

   }
```

Comment: Hi inner class. Thanks for your response. I made the changes that you asked but it still doesn't work. I have the gist listed in one of the comments above in case you want to take a look at my complete code. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make some changes to your activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in MainACtivity you have to use this `frame_container` id to replace your fragment with

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
        return rootView;
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(bala,bala, bala, cause i don't remember ) {

       LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new PaletteAdapter(generatePalettes()));
    }
```